# How do I reset view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I got a view controller class with over 100 variables in it declared in the .h file. When I press play again I want the the scene to reset from scratch and all variables to reset. How do I do this?

Comment: create new view self.myView = [MyViewClass new];

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, I see here:

A) Create a new instance of your UIView or UIViewController

B) Write a method `- (void)reset`, that resets all variables to the default state.

For example

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self reset];
    }
}

// Call on creation, to have it filled initially and call on reset
- (void)reset
{
    _foo = YES;
    _bar = @10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. if you want to clear you view , then get all subview & remove them .

   ```
   [[[self view] subviews]
       makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
   ```

that will clear every subview from your view.

2- if you want to reset variable , just assign nil to them

```
-(void)reset{
 self.myVariable=nil;//so
}
```